# Save simulated datasets individually (speed + memory limit)

Tags: r, performance, memory, storage, simulation

I am working with a very large number (say two million) simulated datasets that are created in a for-loop and listed in groups of 2000. I would like to save all 1000 lists of 2000 datasets somewhere, such that I can perform any analysis without having to generate data again. 
Saving all two million datasets in a nested list exceeds memory, so that is not an option. Therefore, I tried to save them per sublist in a workspace:

```
# Generate data
data_list <- vector("list", 2000)

for(i in 1:1000){
    for(j in 1:2000){
        dataA <- cbind(rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j))
        dataB <- cbind(rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j))
        data_list[[j]] <- dataA-dataB
    }

# Write to workspace
assign(paste("Data",i,sep=""), data_list)

# Add to existing workspace and remove object (to save memory).
if(file.exists("Workspaces.RData")){  
    old.objects <- load("Workspaces.RData")
    save(list=c(old.objects, paste("Data",i,sep="")),file="Workspaces.RData") 
    rm(list=c(old.objects,paste("Data",i,sep="")))

# Or create new workspace if it does not exist
}else{
    save(list=paste("Data",i,sep=""), file="Workspaces.RData")
    rm(list=paste("Data",i,sep=""))}
}
```

This is a very slow solution for the number and sizes of datasets I am working with, so I was wondering whether anyone has a better solution to store and load generated datasets.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This does not look like simulating your scenario. Can you edit the code so that it represents the data sizes you are dealing with? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: Don't use `.RData`, use `.rds` with `saveRDS`. You'll be able to name your files more easily. And you'll be able to name your data when loading your files.

Comment: @minem, I edited the code (increased the number of loops). Could you explain why that matters for this particular case? 
How do I find out about RAM? R only tells me that it cannot allocate a vector of so many GBs (not sure how many exactly).

Comment: @Suzanne It is hard to help in case when you are not supplying exactly what are you doing and simulating. Because, the case in your example is trivial and should not be done with loops. Maybe the same is true with your real simulations? About RAM: [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+find+out+how+much+ram+you+have)

Comment: @minem I see. I removed a lot of stuff to create a minimal working example, but maybe I should add some more information. How would you solve the example case without loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by F.Privé, if you need to save those files, better use saveRDS. In that case you are not doing redundant saving and loading.

```
jj <- 1:2000
for(i in 1:10){
  for(j in jj){
    dataA <- cbind(rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j))
    dataB <- cbind(rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j),rnorm(j))
    data_list[[j]] <- dataA-dataB
  }
  saveRDS(data_list, paste0("Data", i, '.rds'))
}
```

As of this particular data simulation, I would try to avoid loops. Generating all the data at once (or at least in parts) and then storing to data.frame with index column. Something like:

```
dataA <- replicate(8, rnorm(sum(jj)))
dataB <- replicate(8, rnorm(sum(jj)))
data_list <- dataA - dataB
data <- as.data.frame(data_list)
data[, "ind"] <- rep(jj, times = jj)
```

But as I assume this is not your real data simulation, it is crucial to understand why you are simulating 1k list of 2k data sets? Do they all need to be in separated lists? All are simulated equally? and so on...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see your point. Indeed, my real simulation needed all these separate lists. I will mention that in my question next time.